# If log buffer is full, how dose mysql to handle large uncommitted transaction?

Tags: mysql, innodb

mysql will write some parts of log to redo file？？？As far as I know,redo logs(ib_logfile) are used in a circular fashion. When redo logs are full,and there are some large uncommitted transaction in redo logo,how dose mysql deal with this situatuin???

Answer (score 0):

The 'overflow' goes into the rows.  This implies that performance suffers for 'large' transactions.  (That is, large compared to the log file size.)  Actually I suspect it is not so much the "overflow", but the "first" changes that get moved.

So, to address your implied question, *any* size transaction can be handled, fully ACID.